# Nuxt.js Server side plugin function is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I created a server side plugin and I'm getting

> context.app.handleServerError is not a function

// hanlde-server-error.js

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  app.handleServerError = (method, error, data) => {
    const message = `An error occured in ${method}. ${error}`
    console.error(message)
    Sentry.captureException(new Error(message))
  }
}
```

// nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/handle-server-error', mode: 'server' },
  ],
```

// calling function

```
  async asyncData(context) {
    // await store.dispatch('fetchAccounts')
    try {
      await undefinedFunction()
    } catch (error) {
      context.app.handleServerError('asyncData', error, { user: 'bambam' })
    }
  },
```

Am I correct that asyncData makes the call server side?
According to the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) this function should be available on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute it **only** server side.

```
async asyncData(context) {
  if (process.server) {
    try {
      await undefinedFunction()
    } catch (error) {
      context.app.handleServerError('asyncData', error, { user: 'bambam' })
    }
  }
},
```